# Multiuser in Android Studio using Realtime Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

When I run the codes, it does not show any error. I have no problem to login as guardian but when I try to login as elderly it couldn't and I don't know what's the problem. What I want is when a user input the username and password, it will validate from database and direct the user according to different user type.

Segment codes of Login.java:

```
private Boolean validateUsername() {

    String val = username.getEditText().getText().toString();

    if (val.isEmpty()) {
        username.setError("Field cannot be empty");
        return false;
    } else {
        username.setError(null);
        username.setErrorEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }
}

private Boolean validatePassword() {
    String val = password.getEditText().getText().toString();

    if (val.isEmpty()) {
        password.setError("Field cannot be empty");
        return false;
    } else {
        password.setError(null);
        password.setErrorEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }
}

public void loginUser(View view) {
    //validate login info
    if (!validateUsername() || !validatePassword()) {
        return;
    } else {
        isUser();
    }

}

private void isUser() {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference.child("user").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String input1 = username.getEditText().getText().toString();
            String input2 = password.getEditText().getText().toString();

            if (dataSnapshot.child(input1).exists()) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(input1).child("password").getValue(String.class).equals(input2)) {
                    if (active.isChecked()) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(input1).child("radioGuardian").getValue(String.class).equals("Guardian")) {
                            preferences.setDataLogin(Login.this, true);
                            preferences.setDataAs(Login.this, "Guardian");
                            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, dashboardGuardian.class));
                        } else if (dataSnapshot.child(input1).child("radioElderly").getValue(String.class).equals("Elderly")) {
                            preferences.setDataLogin(Login.this, true);
                            preferences.setDataAs(Login.this, "Elderly");
                            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, dashboardUser.class));
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(input1).child("radioGuardian").getValue(String.class).equals("Guardian")) {
                            preferences.setDataLogin(Login.this, false);
                            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, dashboardGuardian.class));

                        } else if (dataSnapshot.child(input1).child("radioElderly").getValue(String.class).equals("Elderly")) {
                            preferences.setDataLogin(Login.this, false);
                            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, dashboardUser.class));
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    password.setError("Wrong Password");
                    password.requestFocus();
                }
            } else {
                username.setError("No such User exist");
                username.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}


protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (preferences.getDataLogin(this)) {
        if (preferences.getDataAs(this).equals("Guardian")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, dashboardGuardian.class));
            finish();
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, dashboardUser.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Codes of Register.java:

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

//Variables
TextInputLayout regUsername, regEmail, regPhoneNo, regPassword;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton selectedElderly, selectedGuardian;
Button regBtn, regToLoginBtn;
UserHelperClass helperClass;
int i = 0;

FirebaseDatabase rootNode;
DatabaseReference reference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    //Hooks to all xml elements in activity_register.xml
    regUsername = findViewById(R.id.reg_username);
    regEmail = findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
    regPhoneNo = findViewById(R.id.reg_phoneNo);
    regPassword = findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
    regBtn = findViewById(R.id.reg_btn);
    regToLoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.reg_login_btn);
    radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radio_type);
    selectedGuardian = findViewById(R.id.radioGuardian);
    selectedElderly = findViewById(R.id.radioElderly);
    helperClass = new UserHelperClass();

    regBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (validateUsername() && validateEmail() && validatePhoneNo() && validateUserType() && validatePassword() == true) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                validateUsername();
                validateEmail();
                validatePhoneNo();
                validateUserType();
                validatePassword();
            }

            rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            reference = rootNode.getReference("user");

            //Get all the values
            String m1 = selectedElderly.getText().toString();
            String m2 = selectedGuardian.getText().toString();
            String username = regUsername.getEditText().getText().toString();
            String password = regPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();
            helperClass.setUsername(regUsername.getEditText().getText().toString());
            helperClass.setEmail(regEmail.getEditText().getText().toString());
            helperClass.setPhoneNo(regPhoneNo.getEditText().getText().toString());
            helperClass.setPassword(regPassword.getEditText().getText().toString());
            if (selectedElderly.isChecked()) {
                helperClass.setRadioElderly(m1);

            } else {
                helperClass.setRadioGuardian(m2);
            }
            reference.child(username).setValue(helperClass);
        }
    });
    regToLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

private Boolean validateUsername() {
    String val = regUsername.getEditText().getText().toString();
    String noWhiteSpace = "\\A\\w{4,20}\\z";

    if (val.isEmpty()) {
        regUsername.setError("Field cannot be empty");
        return false;
    } else if (val.length() >= 15) {
        regUsername.setError("Username too long");
        return false;
    } else if (!val.matches(noWhiteSpace)) {
        regUsername.setError("White space is not allowed");
        return false;
    } else {
        regUsername.setError(null);
        regUsername.setErrorEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }
}

private Boolean validateEmail() {
    String val = regEmail.getEditText().getText().toString();
    String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

    if (val.isEmpty()) {
        regEmail.setError("Field cannot be empty");
        return false;
    } else if (!val.matches(emailPattern)) {
        regEmail.setError("Invalid email address");
        return false;
    } else {
        regEmail.setError(null);
        return true;
    }
}

private Boolean validatePhoneNo() {
    String val = regPhoneNo.getEditText().getText().toString();

    if (val.isEmpty()) {
        regPhoneNo.setError("Field cannot be empty");
        return false;
    } else {
        regPhoneNo.setError(null);
        return true;
    }
}

private Boolean validateUserType() {
    if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please select user type", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

private Boolean validatePassword() {
    String val = regPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();
    String passwordVal = "^" +
            "(?=.*[0-9])" +  //at least 1 digit
            "(?=.*[a-z])" +  //at least 1 lower case letter
            "(?=.*[A-Z])" +  //at least 1 upper case letter
            "(?=.*[a-zA-Z])" +  //any letter
            "(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])" +  //at least 1 special character
            "(?=\\S+$)" +  //no white space
            ".{4,}" +  //at least 4 characters
            "$";

    if (val.isEmpty()) {
        regPassword.setError("Field cannot be empty");
        return false;
    } else if (!val.matches(passwordVal)) {
        regPassword.setError("Password is too weak");
        return false;
    } else {
        regPassword.setError(null);
        regPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }
}

public void registerUser(View view) {
    if (!validateUsername() | !validatePassword() | !validatePhoneNo() | !validateEmail() | validateUserType()) {
        return;
    }
    //Get all the values
    String m1 = selectedElderly.getText().toString();
    String m2 = selectedGuardian.getText().toString();
    helperClass.setUsername(regUsername.getEditText().getText().toString());
    helperClass.setEmail(regEmail.getEditText().getText().toString());
    helperClass.setPhoneNo(regPhoneNo.getEditText().getText().toString());
    helperClass.setPassword(regPassword.getEditText().getText().toString());
    if (selectedElderly.isChecked()) {
        helperClass.setRadioElderly(m1);

    } else {
        helperClass.setRadioGuardian(m2);
    }
    reference.child(String.valueOf(i + 1)).setValue(helperClass);
}
}
```

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMYaM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you post your database structure that would be more helpful.

As per your code.
you have two children in input1

'radioGuardian' and 'radioElderly'

have you added both values on registration? Or it will be null. And it will produce nullPointEx.
Hence the issue is here!

```
if (selectedElderly.isChecked()) {
            helperClass.setRadioElderly(m1);
        } else {
            helperClass.setRadioGuardian(m2);
        }
```

Try to change it to:-

```
    if (selectedElderly.isChecked()) {
            helperClass.setRadioElderly(m1);
            helperClass.setRadioGuardian("NA");
        } else {
            helperClass.setRadioGuardian(m2);
            helperClass.setRadioElderly("NA");
                }
```

Comment: I have change it to that you show me but still doesn't work. Can you see my database structure I just uploaded above and if can please help me out with that...

Comment: @Sally you have changed the code but it is not saved on the database. You will need to re-register the user. So that there is value for both setRadioElderly and setRadioGuardian for every user. In simple words. Your app is crashing because it's not able to find the child.

Comment: Check for space.

Comment: thankss a lot ya, my problem have been solved!

Comment: @Sally Glad to help